# Encoding issues with Ruby-2.4.1

Tags: ruby, encoding

I am having different output of following line with different version of ruby:

```
puts "#{"%c"%[254]}"
```

Output from `ruby-2.4.1`  :    **þ**

Output from `ruby-1.8.7`  :    **�**

It looks like issue with encoding, as there is no encoding in `Ruby-1.8.7`

Can someone please help me to get same result as `Ruby-1.8.7` in `Ruby-2.4.1` also?

This result is desirable because Ruby-1.8.7 gives me "**254"** after decoding while Ruby-2.4.1 gives me following error

*`%': **invalid value for Integer(): "þ" (ArgumentError)***

Comment: That said, you want to get an `U+FFFD` codepoint reserved for [replacement character](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=FFFD)? Just print it out: �, there is no other way to get it from `þ`.

Comment: Ruby 1.8 had only limited support for Unicode. Do you really need this to work in a Ruby version that was released almost 10 years ago and reached its end of life more than 4 years ago?

Comment: Why do you find that 1.8.7 result more desirable?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, 1.8.7 result is desirable as it is giving me "254" after decoding. Please check following issue with Ruby-2.4.1 :

*puts "#{"%d"%[ þ]}"*

Output :-  **`%': invalid value for Integer(): "þ" (ArgumentError)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Ruby 1.8.7, as I started Ruby with version 2.3, but this looks promising: https://gist.github.com/afair/2911107

But as everyone else is saying it would be best to upgrade your Ruby version if at all possible. Older versions of Ruby had limited Unicode support.

Comment: There is a problem with decoding in Ruby-2.4.1, which is throwing error :

**%': invalid value for Integer(): "þ" (ArgumentError)**